# In React-Bootstrap or Bootstrap col into col (without row) is allowed?

Tags: reactjs, user-interface, react-redux, react-bootstrap

It's allow in React-Bootstrap or React?

```html
<row>
 <col>
  <col>
   It's good or bad or Allow?
  </col>
 <col/>
</row>
```

Comment: There is no connection between bootstrap and HTML's col tag element and yes you can use nested HTML col tags. Bootstrap has its own col class which is related with CSS style. It is nothing to do with an html element.

Answer (score 1):

Col is like container for elements. You can put children cols int parent cols.

Comment: But, as per rules of Bootstrap it's not allowed to nest the cols in col directly so, this rule is also be applied to React-Bootstrap?

Comment: A row is flex container and a col is flex item. In col you can serve elements but its you can't control. So you can hack it with class d-flex. But with a row it will be by best practices. And about flex you can see [there](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/).